# При скролле сайт скрывает элементы

Tags: html, jquery, css

При загрузке сайт выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скролла по умолчанию у страницы нет, но когда пользователь прокручивает сайт пол сайта просто скрывается, элементы остаются кликабельными но при этом их не видно, при ресайзе сайт восстанавливается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если необходима дополнительная информация, добавлю. Я даже понятия не имею с чем связана проблема.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <title>WEB-SITE!</title>
</head>
<body>


<section class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="logo_black col-lg-2">
                <h4>Lotcar.ru</h4>
                <hr>
                <p>8 (800) 555-35-35</p>
            </div>
            <div class="menu_red offset-6 col-lg-4">
                <p>Новости</p>
                <a href="#">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" id="Capa_1" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 56 56" style="enable-background:new 0 0 56 56;" xml:space="preserve" width="50px" height="50px">
                        <g>
                            <path d="M28,0C12.561,0,0,12.561,0,28s12.561,28,28,28s28-12.561,28-28S43.439,0,28,0z M28,54C13.663,54,2,42.336,2,28   S13.663,2,28,2s26,11.664,26,26S42.337,54,28,54z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                            <path d="M40,16H16c-0.553,0-1,0.448-1,1s0.447,1,1,1h24c0.553,0,1-0.448,1-1S40.553,16,40,16z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                            <path d="M40,27H16c-0.553,0-1,0.448-1,1s0.447,1,1,1h24c0.553,0,1-0.448,1-1S40.553,27,40,27z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                            <path d="M40,38H16c-0.553,0-1,0.448-1,1s0.447,1,1,1h24c0.553,0,1-0.448,1-1S40.553,38,40,38z" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<div class="circle"></div>

<section class="news">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <H1>НАШИ НОВОСТИ</H1>
            <div class="col-lg-4 news-card">
                <div class="img">
                    <img src="img/News-Page/Lexus.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <h4>ЭТО ЛЕХУХ</h4>
                    <p>Таким образом укрепление
                        и развитие структуры позволяет
                        выполнять важные задания по
                        разработке системы обучения
                        кадров, соответствует насущным
                        потребностям. Равным образом
                        начало повседневной работы</p>
                    <div style="float: left;">
                        <svg height="12px" id="Capa_1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 511.626 511.626;" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 511.626 511.626" width="12px" x="0px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" y="0px">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M505.918,236.117c-26.651-43.587-62.485-78.609-107.497-105.065c-45.015-26.457-92.549-39.687-142.608-39.687 c-50.059,0-97.595,13.225-142.61,39.687C68.187,157.508,32.355,192.53,5.708,236.117C1.903,242.778,0,249.345,0,255.818 c0,6.473,1.903,13.04,5.708,19.699c26.647,43.589,62.479,78.614,107.495,105.064c45.015,26.46,92.551,39.68,142.61,39.68 c50.06,0,97.594-13.176,142.608-39.536c45.012-26.361,80.852-61.432,107.497-105.208c3.806-6.659,5.708-13.223,5.708-19.699 C511.626,249.345,509.724,242.778,505.918,236.117z M194.568,158.03c17.034-17.034,37.447-25.554,61.242-25.554 c3.805,0,7.043,1.336,9.709,3.999c2.662,2.664,4,5.901,4,9.707c0,3.809-1.338,7.044-3.994,9.704 c-2.662,2.667-5.902,3.999-9.708,3.999c-16.368,0-30.362,5.808-41.971,17.416c-11.613,11.615-17.416,25.603-17.416,41.971 c0,3.811-1.336,7.044-3.999,9.71c-2.667,2.668-5.901,3.999-9.707,3.999c-3.809,0-7.044-1.334-9.71-3.999 c-2.667-2.666-3.999-5.903-3.999-9.71C169.015,195.482,177.535,175.065,194.568,158.03z M379.867,349.04 c-38.164,23.12-79.514,34.687-124.054,34.687c-44.539,0-85.889-11.56-124.051-34.687s-69.901-54.2-95.215-93.222 c28.931-44.921,65.19-78.518,108.777-100.783c-11.61,19.792-17.417,41.207-17.417,64.236c0,35.216,12.517,65.329,37.544,90.362 s55.151,37.544,90.362,37.544c35.214,0,65.329-12.518,90.362-37.544s37.545-55.146,37.545-90.362 c0-23.029-5.808-44.447-17.419-64.236c43.585,22.265,79.846,55.865,108.776,100.783C449.767,294.84,418.031,325.913,379.867,349.04 z" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
                            </g>
                        </svg> <p class="views">410</p>
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: right;">
                        <a class="lMore" href="#">Подробнее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 news-card">
                <div class="img">
                    <img src="img/News-Page/Lexus.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <h4>ЭТО ЛЕХУХ</h4>
                    <p>Таким образом укрепление
                        и развитие структуры позволяет
                        выполнять важные задания по
                        разработке системы обучения
                        кадров, соответствует насущным
                        потребностям. Равным образом
                        начало повседневной работы</p>
                    <div style="float: left;">
                        <svg height="12px" id="Capa_1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 511.626 511.626;" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 511.626 511.626" width="12px" x="0px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" y="0px">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M505.918,236.117c-26.651-43.587-62.485-78.609-107.497-105.065c-45.015-26.457-92.549-39.687-142.608-39.687 c-50.059,0-97.595,13.225-142.61,39.687C68.187,157.508,32.355,192.53,5.708,236.117C1.903,242.778,0,249.345,0,255.818 c0,6.473,1.903,13.04,5.708,19.699c26.647,43.589,62.479,78.614,107.495,105.064c45.015,26.46,92.551,39.68,142.61,39.68 c50.06,0,97.594-13.176,142.608-39.536c45.012-26.361,80.852-61.432,107.497-105.208c3.806-6.659,5.708-13.223,5.708-19.699 C511.626,249.345,509.724,242.778,505.918,236.117z M194.568,158.03c17.034-17.034,37.447-25.554,61.242-25.554 c3.805,0,7.043,1.336,9.709,3.999c2.662,2.664,4,5.901,4,9.707c0,3.809-1.338,7.044-3.994,9.704 c-2.662,2.667-5.902,3.999-9.708,3.999c-16.368,0-30.362,5.808-41.971,17.416c-11.613,11.615-17.416,25.603-17.416,41.971 c0,3.811-1.336,7.044-3.999,9.71c-2.667,2.668-5.901,3.999-9.707,3.999c-3.809,0-7.044-1.334-9.71-3.999 c-2.667-2.666-3.999-5.903-3.999-9.71C169.015,195.482,177.535,175.065,194.568,158.03z M379.867,349.04 c-38.164,23.12-79.514,34.687-124.054,34.687c-44.539,0-85.889-11.56-124.051-34.687s-69.901-54.2-95.215-93.222 c28.931-44.921,65.19-78.518,108.777-100.783c-11.61,19.792-17.417,41.207-17.417,64.236c0,35.216,12.517,65.329,37.544,90.362 s55.151,37.544,90.362,37.544c35.214,0,65.329-12.518,90.362-37.544s37.545-55.146,37.545-90.362 c0-23.029-5.808-44.447-17.419-64.236c43.585,22.265,79.846,55.865,108.776,100.783C449.767,294.84,418.031,325.913,379.867,349.04 z" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
                            </g>
                        </svg> <p class="views">410</p>
                    </div>
                    <div style="float: right;">
                        <a class="lMore" href="#">Подробнее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 news-card">
                <div class="img">
                    <img src="img/News-Page/Lexus.png" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="content">
                    <h4>ЭТО ЛЕХУХ</h4>
                    <p>Таким образом укрепление
                        и развитие структуры позволяет
                        выполнять важные задания по
                        разработке системы обучения
                        кадров, соответствует насущным
                        потребностям. Равным образом
                        начало повседневной работы</p>
                    <div style="float: left;">
                        <svg height="12px" id="Capa_1" style="enable-background:new 0 0 511.626 511.626;" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 511.626 511.626" width="12px" x="0px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" y="0px">
                            <g>
                                <path d="M505.918,236.117c-26.651-43.587-62.485-78.609-107.497-105.065c-45.015-26.457-92.549-39.687-142.608-39.687 c-50.059,0-97.595,13.225-142.61,39.687C68.187,157.508,32.355,192.53,5.708,236.117C1.903,242.778,0,249.345,0,255.818 c0,6.473,1.903,13.04,5.708,19.699c26.647,43.589,62.479,78.614,107.495,105.064c45.015,26.46,92.551,39.68,142.61,39.68 c50.06,0,97.594-13.176,142.608-39.536c45.012-26.361,80.852-61.432,107.497-105.208c3.806-6.659,5.708-13.223,5.708-19.699 C511.626,249.345,509.724,242.778,505.918,236.117z M194.568,158.03c17.034-17.034,37.447-25.554,61.242-25.554 c3.805,0,7.043,1.336,9.709,3.999c2.662,2.664,4,5.901,4,9.707c0,3.809-1.338,7.044-3.994,9.704 c-2.662,2.667-5.902,3.999-9.708,3.999c-16.368,0-30.362,5.808-41.971,17.416c-11.613,11.615-17.416,25.603-17.416,41.971 c0,3.811-1.336,7.044-3.999,9.71c-2.667,2.668-5.901,3.999-9.707,3.999c-3.809,0-7.044-1.334-9.71-3.999 c-2.667-2.666-3.999-5.903-3.999-9.71C169.015,195.482,177.535,175.065,194.568,158.03z M379.867,349.04 c-38.164,23.12-79.514,34.687-124.054,34.687c-44.539,0-85.889-11.56-124.051-34.687s-69.901-54.2-95.215-93.222 c28.931-44.921,65.19-78.518,108.777-100.783c-11.61,19.792-17.417,41.207-17.417,64.236c0,35.216,12.517,65.329,37.544,90.362 s55.151,37.544,90.362,37.544c35.214,0,65.329-12.518,90.362-37.544s37.545-55.146,37.545-90.362 c0-23.029-5.808-44.447-17.419-64.236c43.585,22.265,79.846,55.865,108.776,100.783C449.767,294.84,418.031,325.913,379.867,349.04 z" fill="#FFFFFF"></path>
                            </g>
                        </svg> <p class="views">410</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="lMore" style="float: right;">
                        <a class="lMore" href="#">Подробнее</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#">ПОКАЗАТЬ БОЛЬШЕ</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>




<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/SmoothScroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/slick.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/applicate.min.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xyp5hf6k/)

Comment: Вы бы хоть код приложили. Тут по фото не гадают

Comment: @Hikikomori, так беда в том, что я не знаю какой именно крепить, весь HTML, CSS, JQ скидывать?

Comment: ну разумеется весь ...надо видеть проблему что бы её решить

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, обновил вопрос, прикрепил JSFiddle

Comment: @user302308 Я пока проблем не вижу, возможно из-за того, что подключены не все скрипты. Трех последних нет. Попробуйте тоже их временно отключить и если проблема исчезнет - подключайте по одному до возникновения. Раз у вас свзязано со скроллом, то есть подозрение на SmoothScroll.js, но надо проверять.

Comment: я тоже не вижу проблемы - наверно не всё подключено